# Is it possible to cast returned value before returning?

Tags: java, generics

I heard about generic, but I can't find a way to make it return already casted value.
For example:

```
public <T> T getController(SceneEnum sceneEnum) {
    if (sceneData.get(sceneEnum) == null) {
        initScene(sceneEnum);
    }
    return sceneData.get(sceneEnum).getLoader().getController();
}
```

this method returns different classes, for example MainScreenControler, PopupController etc.
but I can't call method from returned class, without casting it.

- works:
  ((MainScreenController)getController(MainScreenEnum)).someMethod();
- doesn't work: getController(MainScreenEnum).someMethod();

So is there any way to perform casting inside getter?

Comment: Generic parameter `T` is unbound and thus could be anything (e.g. `Integer`). I would expect that generic parameter `T` is used somewhere in the statement after `return ...`.

Comment: so case from "doesn't work" row isn't possible? Because even if I bound it with some parent class of controllers, I anyway should cast it to child to call specific methods?

Comment: Just as a note, you should consider learning generics before trying to just use them without really understanding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method of casting safely with generics:

```
public <T> T getController(SceneEnum sceneEnum, Class<T> clazz) {
    if (sceneData.get(sceneEnum) == null) {
        initScene(sceneEnum);
    }

    Object controller = sceneData.get(sceneEnum).getLoader().getController();
    if (clazz.isInstance(controller)) {
      return (T) controller;
    } else {
      throw new ClassCastException("Failed to cast");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify generic explicitly

```
this.<MainScreenController>getController(MainScreenEnum).someMethod();
```

inside the class containing `getController` or

```
instance.<MainScreenController>getController(MainScreenEnum).someMethod();
```

inside a different class (`instance` is an instance of the class containing `getController`).

Unfortunately, this is hardly shorter than

```
((MainScreenController) getController(MainScreenEnum)).someMethod();
```

You can't "cast" inside getter because `T` is decided in a call site, not in the definition site.